# Why can't I seed a user using EF 6 Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, seeding

Like the title says, I'm using Entity Framework 6. When I call Update-Database, the seed method fails:

```
SimpleMembershipProvider userMgr = new SimpleMembershipProvider();

if (WebSecurity.Initialized)
{
   if (userMgr.GetUser("administrator", false) == null) //--> Throws the exception
   {
      userMgr.CreateUserAndAccount("administrator", "password", false, null)
      ...
   }
}
```

And the exception that gets thrown:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.
   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.get_PreviousProvider()
   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)
   at SomeProject.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(SomeProjectDB context) in c:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SomeProject\SomeProject 2.0\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 73
   ...
```

Comment: The exception gives you instructions on what to do. Does following those instructions not work?